# How to prevent GtkWindow growing?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

This is my codes:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
   GtkWidget* window, *button, *grid;
   gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

   window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),100,100);
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
   //gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);
   gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);

   grid = gtk_grid_new();
   button = gtk_button_new_with_label("1");
   gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0,0, 100, 1);
   gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid), TRUE);
   gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid), TRUE);

   button = gtk_button_new_with_label("1");
   gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button,0, 1, 10, 1);
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);
   gtk_widget_show_all(window);
   gtk_main();
   return 0;
}
```

the result of this codes is :
[gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button,0, 1, 100, 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DU9L.png)

When I change gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button,0, 1, 100, 1) to gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button,0, 1, 200, 1)
Then the result of this code is:
[gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button,0, 1, 200, 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9YOZ.png)

Why does the width of window increase? I find that the size of window may be varied with the function gtk_grid_attach(). So how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the width of window increase?

You have used

```c
   gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid), TRUE);
   gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid), TRUE);
```

Which means that each cell in the grid will have equal width and height, which will be the same as the largest widget embedded. So If you have more cells, the grid will grow further and thus the window width increases

> I find that the size of window may be varied with the function gtk_grid_attach(). So how to solve it?

I don't know what's your usecase is. But you could unset the homogeneous properties and/or use a real grid width and height when attaching children.

Comment: You recommended me to use real grid width and height when attaching children. But how can I know the real grid width and height? Threre are no functions to set the number of rows and columns in a grid.

Comment: @noob Check [This Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpNTZk3PIi-Z5SiFNeUyj6Z). Maybe it will bring you on the right track.